# trouble with non-latin characters

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble with my page. I have moved my site from a host provider to another one, and now i'm having some problems with non-latin characters, for text that comes from db query and for text that is in html/php file.
For text that comes from db someone suggested me to apply this after db connection:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

and it did the trick, but, now i'm having the same problem for texts that comes from html/php files: instead of ë or ç appears �
I'm sure that should be e trick someone on the server or somewhere else on the configuration.
Hope that you can help me.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

i'm using at the header of my file.

Answer (score 2):

You must have this line in your `<head>` section:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: He already uses that. It was only eaten by this site because it wasn't properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Is the collation of your database where the data is stored in utf8_general_ci?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there was a problem while transfering the files.

If you are familiar with Linux, try to fix the broken files on your server with [recode](http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/)
(excerpt: "The Recode library converts files between character sets and usages.")

Comment: ... if you can't choose the character set in the options of your file transfer tool.